# Where I can find openGl library for visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

I need openGL library (gl.h - glu.h - glut.h - glaux.h) for visual studio 2012
Can someone give me link for download this library

Comment: Here you go: google.com

Comment: The Windows SDK includes `gl.h`.  For access to modern OpenGL features, you'll need to load extensions.  A loader library such as GLee or GLEW makes that easy.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenGL headers come by default with Visual C++. There's nothing you've to install to get them. However to make use of modern OpenGL versions you must load newer functionality through the extension mechanism. There are wrappers for this, like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net).